# Remove class attribute name dynamically in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have four divs,each with a button called "create", when on click of this button i'm enabling the ".create" class to this div.
Case: When user clicks on first div and then clicks on the second div create button,how to delete the previous divs ".create".
My code

```
createOne: function(e){
        window.createOne = this;

        var widgetData = this.model;


        $(".create").parent().remove()// i tried in tis way,but it is not deleting class for previos divs

        createOne.set("is_create", true);
}
```

Anyone help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".create").removeClass("create");
```

And only add the new create after you did this.

Comment: This will delete all previous .create classes right?

Comment: Okay will try,how to delete only previous occurence

Comment: You'd probably have to store it in a javascript variable.